# login user control works in one page but not another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have written a simple login user control which includes panels for login and password reminder. Code shown below.

```
 Protected Sub btnForgot_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnForgot.Click
    'User requesting to be sent their username and password
    lblWarning.Text = ""
    Me.panFormWrapper.Visible = False
    Me.panForgot.Visible = True
    txtUsernameReset.Text = ""

    Me.panConfirmSend.Visible = False

End Sub
```

This control sits on two pages...the main login and another registration based page, the only difference being the Master pages they use. The default login page works and the control turns on and off the panels as expected. the other page when clickin the link hides the login form as expected but does NOT display the reminder panel.

Comment: Could you also post the markup? This might help.